# Storing seeds in the fridge

Tags: storage

I would like to store seeds in my fridge because that is what the school is doing. It seems to be very effective. They had lettuce in there that germinated with a 95% rate. That is 6 yr old seed! I am very impressed which is why I get the idea. But I wanted to ask this group if there is anything wrong with the idea of storing seeds in the fridge. Is there seeds that can't handle it (for any reason). Really just wanting to make sure that there is nothing wrong with storing my seeds in the fridge.

Comment: Depends on the plant, but generally, I never store mine in the fridge - I make sure they're dry, then parcel them in foil, pop in an envelope, write on the outside what they are, seal the envelope and all seeds are kept inside a large tin, lid closed, in a cool place. Some plant seeds will keep longer than others naturally, those that don't keep well might be kept below freezing in a seed bank to offset that, but that's not possible at home.

Comment: Yes. Fridge ends up with all sorts of nasty molds and bacteria. It's also moist in there. Cool dark place, immune from rodents and insects.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Okay, I really didn't put the most thought into this. But I have yet to put anything in the fridge because I do like to make sure that something is a good idea in the first place. I will just keep doing what I have done, place the seeds on the shelf by the basement stairs, cool, dark and dry.

Answer (score 1):

Often nature gives us hints. Lettuce growth (in wild) in region where winter is cold, so seeds must survive (also at freezing temperatures).

So I do no see problems. But as you have learn in Physics class, humidity will condense on low temperature (on wild: you have snow, so solid, or dew, which is then absorb by soil, but not constant water), so you could put the bag in refrigerator, when it is cold, remove water and put inside the seeds. Or some rice will also help to keep drop of water away.

Note: for plant of warm region (without cold winter) things are different, and some plants are vivipars: they carry children on "belly" like in humans, and they disperse seedling later (you see it on some garlic and if you look carefully also on some grasses). And some plants need cold temperatures, warm temperature and then again cold temperature. So do no take this answer generally, every plant is special.